# Difference between read and seek (Random Access)

Tags: file, random-access

I do not quite understand what is the difference from read and seek. My prof says that seek is a more advanced version of read, which separates the "movement from the operation". But unfortunately, I am not quite sure what that means.

I also have a vague notion that seek moves the current position, such that all future read and writes will implicitly calculate the offset from said current position. Is this correct? If so, then how is seek a replacement of the read operation? They seem to do different things, but my notes say that linux uses seek instead of read.

Answer (score 2):

A `read` call will read the specified amount of bytes from a "file". I use "file" because the actual target can be a directory, a network socket, or even a pipe dynamically generated by a different program. If the target is actually a file as we know it, which usually support seeking, read call will also advance the position of the offset according to how much bytes it read. Think of it as playing a song, if you listen for a minute and pause, you're in the one-minute mark, and if you continue (`read`), you'll continue from that last point. If you want to go to the end of the song, you'll have to listen (and wait) for the song duration, so the operation is O(n).

Now seeking is the equivalent of just scrolling the bar to whatever position you want. It doesn't read anything in-between the jump. This is what your professor meant with separating the movement from the operation. Thus jumping around the file is an O(1) operation. Obviously this is only possible if the file supports random access. Files stored in your hard drive/SSD do, but magnetic tape (which was common during Unix development) don't. I'm not sure why your notes say Linux use `seek` instead of `read`. Obviously, when dealing with common files, Linux and other systems can use `seek` to set the offset to interesting data and just read those. For example, ID3v1 tag on MP3 files are located at the last 128 bytes of the file, so the OS will jump to that position to display the song information, before going back to the start of the file if it's told to play the file. However, when reading the song information and playing, the OS will still use `read`